# Message for empty ListView in Tab - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost, textview

I have a tab with a list view and another activity. That's my code:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();   
TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListNoteActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator(getString(R.string.list), 
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_new)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NewNoteActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("view").setIndicator(getString(R.string.view),
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_new)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

How can i show message or a TextView if my list in tab 0 is empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ListActivity, set this layout as the content view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="No Items!"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ListActivity will automatically display the text view if the list view is empty. The rest of your activity code remains exactly the same.

Comment: Can you programmatically set the text on the message textview ?